# saving a powerpoint file with a variable name under given path

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I have an active Excel file which has a Name "makroyigit.xlsm".This Name is variable but i think i should be able to extract this Name with a function. I know i get the whole path by

```
       ThisWorkbook.FullName
```

I can then assing the fullname as a variable and if possible i would like to assign the filename as variable.

My macro then opens a new PowerPointslide and pastes some Content from my Excel file. Then it saves this PowerPoint file under this Name and path;

```
     PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.SaveAs "Z:\1000_Entwicklung\somefilename.ppt",1
```

I would like to put the name of my Excel file in to this path, so i want it to be substituted with somefilename.ppt.

I know i should assign the excel file name to a variable then put this variable in to the path but how do i do this ?

Comment: So you want to replace the `somefilename` part with the name of the workbook? If so, just: `"Z:\1000_Entwicklung\" & Replace(Thisworkbook.Name, "xlsm", "ppt")`

Comment: this works perfectly, thanks a lot. What if i want to use the macro again ? then it ll have an error because it is already saved with the filename of the excel.How can i make the automatically filename(2) or so ?

Comment: That's a different question and should be asked as such.